# MapReduce how to reduce the output generated by the reducer?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I am facing an issue in which I want to further reduce the output generate my the reducer. I am using CSV as input. The CSV displays one student absent as every record.

For every ClassRoom, calculate the number of days for which at least five students were absent are recorded in the input data. In the ouput each record in the output should have the number representing the ClassRoom as key and the number of days with at least five students absent as value.

NOTE: The following input displayed is for only the columns from which the data needs to be processed. The original CSV has more thaqn 18 columns with different data in it. So the Date column is column number 10 and and Class column is column number 13.

[INPUT screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTpN9.png)

```
Date    Class  
01/01/2011  12  
03/01/2011  12  
01/01/2011  12  
01/01/2011  12  
01/01/2011  12  
01/01/2011  12  
11/01/2011  12  
11/01/2011  13  
11/01/2011  13  
11/01/2011  13  
11/01/2011  13  
11/01/2011  13  
21/03/2011  14  
21/03/2011  14  
26/04/2011  12  
26/04/2011  12  
26/04/2011  12  
26/04/2011  12  
26/04/2011  12
```

Currently I am trying to use the following Map and Reduce

**MAP :**

```
public static class TestMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
                   throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
        String district = tokens[12];
        String dateColumn = tokens[9];           

        if (districtColumn == "Class") {
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            word.set(district+"|"+dateColumn);
            context.write(word, one);
        }       
    }
}
```

**REDUCER :**

```
public static class TestReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,Text> {
    private Text word = new Text();
    private Text word2 = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
                         throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int no = 0;
        int no2 = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            no += val.get();
        }

        if (no>=5) {
            no2 = 1;
            String S = key.toString();
            String[] A = S.split("\\|");
            word.set(A[0]);
            word2.set(no2);

            context.write(word, word2);
            no2++;
        }    
    }
}
```

**Actual Output :**

```
12 1  
11 1
```

**Expected Output :**

```
12 2  
11 1
```

[Expected OUTPUT screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpiN4.png)

Comment: Hint: only use screen shots as last resort. You are asking to provide code that should work on TEXT. So why dont you put up examples that show your current output and the expected one?!

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat,  actually this is first time I am posting something on StackOverflow. The Expected output I have pasted in as screenshot.           The Actual Output I get is 12  1    11   1

Comment: Dont put more infos into comments; edit your question. And the point is: you should not use links to external screenshots. Always go with pure text first. And only if there is no other way, add a screenshot directly to your question. Dont go external!

Comment: Done. Thanks @GhostCat

Comment: Your input data doesnt match the logic in your mapper, for example it isn't in CSV format, and you are looking for columns 12 and 9 when there are only two.

Comment: My bad @BinaryNerd. The input is CSV and has lots of columns. So I only pasted the column from which data needs to be processed. I will update your question.